# set array content to title of span tag with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have an array like this:

```
var name = ["cat","shark","tiger","snake"];
```

i want set array content to `<span>` title.

HTML CODE:

```
<ul id="select">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>CAT</span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>SHARK</span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>TIGER</span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>SNAKE</span></li>
</ul>
```

jquery code:

```
for(var i=0; i<=name.length; i++){
        $('#select li > span').each(function() {
        this.title = name[i];
        });
    };
```

but this code don't work.
title of span is be undifined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to loop over the spans *and* the array.  Also the `i <= name.length` means that you will always loop *past* the array (should be `<`).  This means that you were actually setting each span's title to an array element that did not exist.

```
$('#select li > span').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('title', name[i]);
});
```

You may also want to check that `name[i]` exists.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtbE5/

Answer (score 3):

If by `title` you mean the *text* of the `span`, I'd suggest:

```
$('#select li span').text(function(i){
    return name[i];
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NevVX/).

Or if you're trying to set the title *attribute*, I'd suggest:

```
$('#select li span').attr('title',function(i){
    return name[i];
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NevVX/1/).

Comment: *doesn't work* where? In the Fiddle? (It does.) In your page? What else is going on that's stopping it? Any errors in the JavaScript console? Can you reproduce your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Have you wrapped the code inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){/* your code in here */});`? And what does "doesn't work" even mean? In what way does it not work? What is it that you *expect*, that it doesn't do?

Comment: thanks for Attention.... in my page,i have wrapped the code inside of a $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#select li span').each(function(i){
    $(this).html(name[i]);
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/r6TNq/)